# pip install dlib fails to find Python.h in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, dlib

I have a python3.6 virtualenv (virtualenv 20.0.13). When I try to install dlib in it using pip, I get the error:

```
/tmp/pip-install-b3996_mv/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:111:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
```

I am able to install dlib outside the virtualenv, but inside I can't.

```
~/venv$ locate Python.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

probable reason is you haven't properly installed libraries for `python-dev`. Install python-dev system wide:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev  # for python3.x
```